# Plotnine (ggplot) : Add whisker to end of geom_segment

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotnine

I am doing this in python's wonderful plotnine package, but hoping ggplotters may have a solution as well.

Consider the following data and plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label' : ['A','B','C','D'], 
    'start' : [1, 1.5, 2.5, 1.75], 
    'end' : [3.85, 2.75, 4.25, 3], 
})
    
p = (ggplot(df, aes(x='label', xend='label', y='start', yend='end'))
  + theme_light()
  + geom_segment()
  + coord_flip()
  + labs(x=None,y=None)
)
p
```

[image]

I would like the segments to end with a whisker or a 'T'.  Kind of like:

[image]

Can this be done?  I have only seen information for arrows (which don't have a 'T' option as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R / ggplot2, at least, you would use `geom_errorbar()` instead of `geom_segment()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
    'label' = c('A','B','C','D'),
    'start' = c(1, 1.5, 2.5, 1.75), 
    'end' = c(3.85, 2.75, 4.25, 3)
)
    
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=label, ymin=start, ymax=end)) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)

p
```

[image]

Note (1) use of `ymin` / `ymax` instead of `y` / `yend`, and (2) use of `width` argument to adjust crossbar size.

Comment: For pythonista's this works in plotnine as well.  Thank you, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about and not aware of any option to achieve that via `arrow`. But one option would be to add your whiskers using a second `geom_segment` for which I add a helper column with the numeric position of the y axis labels:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label' : ['A','B','C','D'], 
    'start' : [1, 1.5, 2.5, 1.75], 
    'end' : [3.85, 2.75, 4.25, 3]
})
df['label_num'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

p = (ggplot(df, aes(x='label', xend='label', y='start', yend='end'))
    + theme_light()
    + geom_segment()
    + geom_segment(aes(y = 'start', yend='start', x = 'label_num - .1', xend = 'label_num + .1'))
    + coord_flip()
    + labs(x=None,y=None))

p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  This is a great solution if I ever want to do on this on one end.  For the moment, I wanted on both ends, so the errorbar was the easier solution for my purposes, but I think this will be useful for others.  Appreciate the help.